# String immutability, pop quiz

Tags: java, string

There are a lot of questions concerning String immutability, but yet I haven't found an answer for why the following happens:

```
1) "TEST".equals("TEST")            // TRUE obviously
2) "TEST" == "TEST"                 // Also TRUE since String's are immutable
3) "TEST" == "T" + "E" + "S" + "T"  // TRUE, but why? Due to compiler optimalization?
4) "TEST" == new String("TEST");    // FALSE, because you explicitly request a new String?
```

Can anyone correct me if necessary and explain in further detail 3 and 4?
Many thanks!

Comment: I feel like this question has popped up like 5 times over the past two weeks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with immutability.

Comment: counterquestion: why do you compare strings with == at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concatenation happens at compile time, so the String goes to the pool, that's why you get `true`.

Regarding the last one, a new object is created because your'e using `new` keyword and comparing the references by `==`, so you're getting `false`.

And this has nothing to do with immutability.